# Finding source of Image for PDF

Tags: javascript, python, django

so I am trying to figure out how I can change the image of this pdf template that was created for me on my Django App. I tried to change the img src to a direct link of the picture that I would like but the result turned out to be the same picture. What might be the best way to change the image?

Here is what appears in the template:

```
               <td width="33%" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                 <img src="/site_media/css/output/images/logo1.jpg"  width="100" style="display:inline; margin-right: 20px"> 
                        </td>
```

The JS file:

```
          $scope.dw_receiving_receipt = function(elem, user, harvest_date) {
        var data = {};
        data.receiving_action_id = 'DASHBOARD';
        data.seller_id = user;
        data.harvest_date = moment(harvest_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        data.plu_code = elem.plu_code.id;
        data.seller_inventory = elem.selected_seller_inventory.seller_inventory;
        $http.post('/inventories/print_receipt/', data, {
                data: JSON
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.save_message = "Receiving receipt fetched successfully.";
                var blob = new Blob([data], {
                        type: "application/pdf;"
                    });
                saveAs(blob, 'receiving_receipt.pdf');
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.save_message = "Could not fetch receiving receipt.";
                alert("Could not fetch receiving receipt.");
            });
    };
```

And the views.py:

```
  def fetch_resources(uri, rel):

if uri == '/site_media/css/output/images/logo.jpg':
    path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR ,"accounts", "static", "accounts", "img","aggri_logo.jpg")
else:
    path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR ,"accounts", "static", "accounts", "img","Logo ALBA Organics.jpg")
return path
```

I have tried many different ways to changing the img src myself but its not budging.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code. Instead, include only code snippets that will reproduce the issue in the question.

Comment: How did you create the PDF Template, have you considered using a PDF formatter such as pyPDF? pyPDF should be able to place images on a PDF.

Comment: I believe we use html2pdf. Im looking to see if there is a similar option for that.